# How to create a mail attachment filename with umlauts and unterscore?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I want to send an email using `javax.mail-api` with mail attachment. The filename should be containing umlauts and unterscore.

To get the right filename, I'm testing as follows:

```
    Session session=Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());
    MimeMessage mimeMsg= new MimeMessage(session);
    mimeMsg.setSubject("Ä_my_test_string","utf-8");
    System.out.println(mimeMsg.getHeader("Subject")[0]);
```

Result: `=?utf-8?Q?=C3=84=5Fmy=5Ftest=5Fstring?=`

Question: hwo can I get a mail subject that is exactly the same as the input string?

Comment: Have you tried actually sending the mail?  I think you'll find that the subject is displayed correctly in most mail readers.  What you're seeing is the subject encoded in the [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding, as e-mail specifications have required for a long time.

Comment: OK, but when I receive the mail for example in `outlook`, the filename contains exactly the string result as above. The "encoded" characters are not interpreted.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried sending that mail to any non-Outlook recipients, such as a free web mail account?

Comment: Indeed I also tried `gmail` but with the same result.

Comment: Strange indeed.  This is a long shot, but… does changing the charset from "utf-8" to "UTF-8" make a difference?

Comment: still not a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

The [javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html) class contains the methods used to encode and decode headers.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(MimeUtility.decodeText("=?utf-8?Q?=C3=84=5Fmy=5Ftest=5Fstring?="));
}
```

Comment: the remote may not have decode functionality. we have to solve it during send phase.